# HttpHandler, Unity, Dependency Injection (DI), web.config is it even possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

```
 public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
 {
      public MyHttpHandler() { ... }

      public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
 }
```

Is there a way to somehow get Container magically be set to a container I setup in global.asax?

Right now I can't find a way of doing it other than using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("container") as IUnityContainer.

Please let me know if there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

First hit on google for `asp.net mvc2 unity`

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/05/07/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-app-using-unity-2-0.aspx

There are plenty of articles about MVC and Unity. You basically need to create a custom controller factory (in mvc2). MVC3 got a different solution.

### Update

Use the [BuildUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660934%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) method in global.asax.

Sry. that was for existing objects. Why not just `Register` it and directly after  `Resolve` it?

Comment: The question is asking about injecting an HttpHandler

Comment: Why can't you add it in global.asax? Unity has a `Build` method if you want to create the `HttpHandler` with all it's dependencies fixed.

Comment: I'm sure you can, your answer doesn't really show how to do this though, it's a link on how to get unity to build your controllers.

Answer (score -3):

Singleton pattern may help you)

Comment: Here is a [link from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) that demonstrates how to implement a singleton pattern.

Answer (score -3):

I would use service location instead.